# Why does setting frame origin in loadView have no effect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to set up my main view without a NIB, so I'm using the loadView method:

**No effect:**

```
-(void)loadView {
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 320, 480);
}
```

**No effect:**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 320, 480);
}
```

**This works:**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear { //or viewWillAppear
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 320, 480);
}
```

(All methods call their respective `super` method, I just didn't put that up there)

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and if there's a way to adjust the view without `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)loadView
{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 320, 480)]];

    self.view = contentView;
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [contentView release];
}
```

[For more visit here](http://code-dojo.blogspot.in/2009/11/build-iphone-application-without.html)

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: Setting the BG color takes effect, but for some reason setting the origin doesn't take effect..

Comment: @mohabitar : I have tested in my app and it worked with setting origin.

Comment: Okkk nm figured it out..turns out that right after my view loads, some other class changes it back to its default frame

Comment: Ok man, Thanks for inform me...So, now i can stop thinking about it..:)

Comment: If you using an UINavigationController as container, the navigation-controller will manipulate your frame.